# Authentication request failure PayPal Android SDK Example

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have to use the PayPal Android SDK, so I'm trying to modify the sample app. 
I have an account in https://developer.paypal.com and I created a REST API app: a pair Client ID - Secret was correctly generated.
In the sample app code, if I set the configuration to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK, I can correctly login before the payment procedure, even if it is a "fake" login. But if I change the configuration to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX, in the authentication login I type email and password of my PayPal Sandobox account (the buyer one, automatically created), it generates an error and the login procedure does not work. The error is:

E/paypal.sdk(5131): request failure with http statusCode:401,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
E/paypal.sdk(5131): request failed with server response:{"error":"invalid_user","error_description":"Invalid user credentials"}
E/paypal.sdk(5131): invalid_user

This is the only activity of the project:

```
package com.paypal.example.paypalandroidsdkexample;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalAuthorization;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalItem;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalOAuthScopes;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPaymentDetails;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ShippingAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Basic sample using the SDK to make a payment or consent to future payments.
 * 
 * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
 * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
 */
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "paymentExample";
    /**
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to move real money.
     * 
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials
     * from https://developer.paypal.com
     * 
     * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires
     * without communicating to PayPal's servers.
     */
    //private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;

    // note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
    //private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "credential from developer.paypal.com";
    //private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AbyTuRxJ5A6RiEILBYbVo1p93DxHrJyRe_VCO9zHSWRBdrXGOEIxjG3KY3jqxDMbhcGHA-y7zQSaSqed";
    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "AVyL8IXt9R6wKM5DlC-opIrFtK7BIGZQqzO5diiGF2fzGLMkPJpQyrv0trkNWppE8qAPyp_G1WqDtC7O";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING = 3;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
            // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
            .merchantName("Example Merchant")
            .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
            .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
        /* 
         * PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE will cause the payment to complete immediately.
         * Change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to 
         *   - PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only authorize payment and capture funds later.
         *   - PAYMENT_INTENT_ORDER to create a payment for authorization and capture
         *     later via calls from your server.
         * 
         * Also, to include additional payment details and an item list, see getStuffToBuy() below.
         */
        PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        /*
         * See getStuffToBuy(..) for examples of some available payment options.
         */

        Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
    }

    private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
        return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "sample item",
                paymentIntent);
    }

    /* 
     * This method shows use of optional payment details and item list.
     */
    private PayPalPayment getStuffToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
        //--- include an item list, payment amount details
        PayPalItem[] items =
            {
                    new PayPalItem("sample item #1", 2, new BigDecimal("87.50"), "USD",
                            "sku-12345678"),
                    new PayPalItem("free sample item #2", 1, new BigDecimal("0.00"),
                            "USD", "sku-zero-price"),
                    new PayPalItem("sample item #3 with a longer name", 6, new BigDecimal("37.99"),
                            "USD", "sku-33333") 
            };
        BigDecimal subtotal = PayPalItem.getItemTotal(items);
        BigDecimal shipping = new BigDecimal("7.21");
        BigDecimal tax = new BigDecimal("4.67");
        PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(shipping, subtotal, tax);
        BigDecimal amount = subtotal.add(shipping).add(tax);
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(amount, "USD", "sample item", paymentIntent);
        payment.items(items).paymentDetails(paymentDetails);

        //--- set other optional fields like invoice_number, custom field, and soft_descriptor
        payment.custom("This is text that will be associated with the payment that the app can use.");

        return payment;
    }

    /*
     * Add app-provided shipping address to payment
     */
    private void addAppProvidedShippingAddress(PayPalPayment paypalPayment) {
        ShippingAddress shippingAddress =
                new ShippingAddress().recipientName("Mom Parker").line1("52 North Main St.")
                        .city("Austin").state("TX").postalCode("78729").countryCode("US");
        paypalPayment.providedShippingAddress(shippingAddress);
    }

    /*
     * Enable retrieval of shipping addresses from buyer's PayPal account
     */
    private void enableShippingAddressRetrieval(PayPalPayment paypalPayment, boolean enable) {
        paypalPayment.enablePayPalShippingAddressesRetrieval(enable);
    }

    public void onFuturePaymentPressed(View pressed) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT);
    }

    public void onProfileSharingPressed(View pressed) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, PayPalProfileSharingActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        intent.putExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_REQUESTED_SCOPES, getOauthScopes());

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING);
    }

    private PayPalOAuthScopes getOauthScopes() {
        /* create the set of required scopes
         * Note: see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/attributes/ for mapping between the
         * attributes you select for this app in the PayPal developer portal and the scopes required here.
         */
        Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>(
                Arrays.asList(PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_EMAIL, PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_ADDRESS) );
        return new PayPalOAuthScopes(scopes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        /**
                         *  TODO: send 'confirm' (and possibly confirm.getPayment() to your server for verification
                         * or consent completion.
                         * See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                         * for more details.
                         *
                         * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
                         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
                         */
                        String paymentId = confirm.toJSONObject().getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
                        Log.d("PROVA", confirm.getProofOfPayment().getPaymentId());


                        Log.d("PROVA", confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString());

                        /*
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(), "Dati ricevuti: " + paymentId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                                */

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        TAG,
                        "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PayPalAuthorization auth =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                if (auth != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);

                        sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Future Payment code received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("FuturePaymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        "FuturePaymentExample",
                        "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
            } 
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PayPalAuthorization auth =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                if (auth != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                        Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", authorization_code);

                        sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Profile Sharing code received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("ProfileSharingExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        "ProfileSharingExample",
                        "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

        /**
         * TODO: Send the authorization response to your server, where it can
         * exchange the authorization code for OAuth access and refresh tokens.
         * 
         * Your server must then store these tokens, so that your server code
         * can execute payments for this user in the future.
         * 
         * A more complete example that includes the required app-server to
         * PayPal-server integration is available from
         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
         */

    }

    public void onFuturePaymentPurchasePressed(View pressed) {
        // Get the Client Metadata ID from the SDK
        String metadataId = PayPalConfiguration.getClientMetadataId(this);

        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "Client Metadata ID: " + metadataId);

        // TODO: Send metadataId and transaction details to your server for processing with
        // PayPal...
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(), "Client Metadata Id received from SDK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop service when done
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paypal.example.paypalandroidsdkexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <!-- for card.io card scanning -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <!-- for most things, including card.io & paypal -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.paypal.example.paypalandroidsdkexample.SampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ProfileSharingConsentActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please, can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Andrea

Comment: Solved creating a new Sandbox test account and typing in the login its credentials. More info here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_about-accounts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest you resetting your sandbox account's password.(The default password is `11111111` for the automatically created account)
[Here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1497&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en) is how to reset the password.